# UITableView and UICollectionView prefetching rect size

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

In iOS 10 Apple introduced quite good feature for UITableView and UICollectionView i.e. data source prefetching. It should be useful if you need to avoid animated loading indicators for images or improve any heavy data loading. So all you need is to implement [UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) or [UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching) respectively and assign to prefetchDataSource property. Everything looks fine. But from my experience prefetching rect size equals to the visible rect size. And in most cases it doesn't give you significant benefits, you still see placeholders in case of fast scrolling.

I tried the solution based on [Preheat](https://github.com/kean/Preheat) and [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) frameworks. It looks good, works better because of provides ability to tune prefetching rect size.

But I'd prefer to use standard mechanism. Furthermore, developer of Preheat+Nuke recommends to use new iOS APIs (honestly, Preheat as well as Nuke have some disadvantages, topic for separate discussion). So all this makes me believe that I missed something. And it is possible to adjust prefetching rect in standard mechanism. Any ideas? Workarounds? Otherwise, I'm in progress with implementing my own mechanism based on standard APIs and Preheat ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kingfisher to load it. it work as asyn. so you can not stuck with it.
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher